# populate listview from database of a separate class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I'm having a hard time finding a way to populate a list view from a database.

here's my code:

> SQLDatabase.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SQLDatabase {

    public static final String KEY_MOVENAME = "movename";
    public static final String KEY_MOVEID = "_moveid";
    public static final String KEY_MOVEDATE = "movedate";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mymovingfriend";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "movingname";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_MOVEID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_MOVEDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MOVENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";


    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public SQLDatabase(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public SQLDatabase open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createMove(String smovename){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_MOVENAME, smovename);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String getMove(){
        String[] column = new String[]{KEY_MOVENAME};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iMove = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOVENAME);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iMove) + "\n";
        }
        c.close();
        return result;
    }

}
```

and here's my listview class, basically this is where the listview its a separate class from the database.

> ListMovingNames.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListMovingNames extends ListActivity {
    ListView MoveList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectorcreatemove);

        MoveList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMoveItems);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

}
```

What I want to do is populate the list view and perform a specific task when one item has been selected from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CursorAdapter to do this. Click to see for CursorAdapter usage 
      http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Answer (score 0):

ok , one approach is to define the variable  for storing the data from database and use this variable while populating data to list view.Here i am reading the database and store the vaules in  other variable.

```
             public List<App_List> getAppList(String appclass){
    List<App_List> App_ListView = new ArrayList<App_List>();
    String AppTable_Name="favorite_apps";
    String AppList_Query="SELECT * FROM " + AppTable_Name +" WHERE appclass = "+ "'"+appclass+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(AppList_Query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            App_List mAppList = new App_List();
            if(cursor.getString(7).equalsIgnoreCase("local")){
                // if application is from local server also take the version
                mAppList.setVersion(cursor.getString(0));
            }
            mAppList.setApp_Name(cursor.getString(3));
            mAppList.setApp_Description(cursor.getString(4));
            mAppList.setApp_Link(cursor.getString(6));
            mAppList.setPlace(cursor.getString(7));//place is added here
            mAppList.setApp_Pkg(cursor.getString(1));
            App_ListView.add(mAppList);
          }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return App_ListView;
```

My class which store value

```
       public class App_List {
private String App_Name;
private String App_Description;
private String App_Link;
private String App_Pkg;
public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}
public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}
private String Version;
private String place;

public String getVersion() {
    return Version;
}
public void setVersion(String version) {
    Version = version;
}
public String getApp_Name() {
    return App_Name;
}
public void setApp_Name(String app_Name) {
    App_Name = app_Name;
}
public String getApp_Description() {
    return App_Description;
}
public void setApp_Description(String app_Description) {
    App_Description = app_Description;
}
public String getApp_Link() {
    return App_Link;
}
public void setApp_Link(String app_Link) {
    App_Link = app_Link;
}
public String getApp_Pkg() {
    return App_Pkg;
}
public void setApp_Pkg(String app_Pkg) {
    App_Pkg = app_Pkg;
}
```

here i am populating the  data to list view

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View mView=convertView;
    if (convertView == null)  
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_adapter, parent,false);
    App_List mAppList= mList.get(position);
    ((TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView_appName)).setText(mAppList.getApp_Name());
    ((TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView_appDescription)).setText(mAppList.getApp_Description());
```